# App, Home lenses not working

Tags: unity, lenses

I've read every possible forum on this topic, however none of them seem to work. 
I have ubuntu 13.10 and i installed gnome 3.10 on it despite the warnings, it was badly incomplete and so i first uninstalled gdm and many more packages, everything went bad after that but i brought back everything to normal except for one thing the home and app lenses.
They are both totally empty and i can't seem to do anything to bring them back. Please Help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I already did all that install reinstall of ubuntu-desktop and lenses but it didn't go away.
But when I tried to open synapse through terminal it showed

> Segmentation Fault

After that I pruged all the databases and all synapse packages and reinstalled it and it started working

Answer (score 0):

Running this should hopefully restore the packages required:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop unity-scope-home unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files
```